# Problem with Continuous Function

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Prove that the range of a continuous function on [1, 4] can
not be the interval (3, 6].

I can't seem to find a solution to this question. I realize I have to use either the Intermediate Value Theorem or the Extreme Value Theorem but I still cannot get a solution.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Continuous image of a compact set is compact. Also, any continuous function on $[1,4]$ attains its minimum value.

Comment: So you mean the minimum value of the function must be within [1,4]? How do I prove that? And how do I prove it is not within (3,6]?

Comment: The interval $(3,6]$ has no smallest number.

Comment: The extreme value theorem says any continuous function on a closed bounded interval takes on a minimum and a maximum value. If the range of the the function is supposed to be $(3,6]$, what are the minimum and maximum values the function takes on?

Comment: The maximum is 6 but the minimum will be 3.00001 something. Basically it does not have a definite minimum therefore it cannot be the range. Right?